# How can i target all the Mobile Devices with the single Asp.net mobile application?

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I am creating ASP.net mobile application i am targeting all the mobile devices Is this possible with the single application or not because some phones will support wml, HTML, CHTML or XML scripting languages. How can target all the devices with the single application & can i change the DeviceSpecific Filter option dynamically or not. If i change that dynamically is it reflect in the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don´t recommend using [mobile controls](http://www.asp.net/mobile/). It is a old (and dead) technology. You could use [MVC](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile), but you will work hard in each rendering.

Answer (score 0):

These technologies were mainly targeted to work on wap... they are old and dead.... currently all mobile phones in the market support at least HTML4... and most smartphones support HTML5 ...

If you want to target mobiles.. make a normal application...only test it on small resolutions...you might need to tweak the css to make it fit on different devices... but in the end it is the same app.

And of course you need to make it touch friendly like not using hover actions and stuff like that.